Why won't marker website links work when two or more markers are on the map?
I'm trying to create a shiny map with icons that, when clicked, link to websites. When only one icon is on the map it works but when there are two or more icons nothing happens?
This is the basic code
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

mydata <- data.frame(site = c(1:2),
                 longitude = c(115.7, 115.8),
                 latitude = c(-32.5,-32.6),
                 address = c("window.open('https://www.google.com.au/')","window.open('http://www.bom.gov.au/')"))


ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", "site",
                     choices = c("Site" = 1,
                                 "Site 2" = 2),
                     selected = 1),
   leafletOutput ("map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addMarkers(data = mydata,
                ~longitude,
                ~latitude,
                group = "checkGroup")
    
    })
    
    mydata_filtered <- reactive(mydata[mydata$site %in% input$checkGroup, ])
    
    observeEvent(input$checkGroup, {
        leafletProxy("map", data = mydata_filtered()) %>%
          clearGroup ("checkGroup") %>%
          addMarkers(lng =  ~longitude,
                    lat = ~latitude,
                    group = "checkGroup",
                    popup= ~paste(
                      actionButton(
                        inputId= "checkGroup",
                        label="Get url",
        
                        onclick=  paste0(address)
                      )))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server,  options = list(launch.browser=T))


This question is similar to: How to pass a list of urls contained in a dataframe column into a leaflet map?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It does not work because with your current approach you only generate one button which contains a list of urls. Instead, here is an approach using lapply which generates a list of buttons passed to popup, this will generate valid HTML.
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

mydata <- data.frame(
    site = c(1:2),
    longitude = c(115.7, 115.8),
    latitude = c(-32.5, -32.6),
    address = c(
        "window.open('https://www.google.com.au/')",
        "window.open('http://www.bom.gov.au/')"
    )
)

mydata$content <-
    lapply(mydata$site, function(site) {
        paste(actionButton(
            inputId = paste0("checkGroup", site),
            label = "Get url",
            onclick =  mydata$address[site]
        ))
    })

ui <- fluidPage(
    checkboxGroupInput(
        "checkGroup",
        "site",
        choices = c("Site" = 1,
                    "Site 2" = 2),
        selected = 1
    ),
    leafletOutput ("map")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles() %>%
            addMarkers(data = mydata,
                       ~ longitude,
                       ~ latitude,
                       group = "checkGroup")
        
    })
    
    mydata_filtered <-
        reactive(mydata[mydata$site %in% input$checkGroup, ])
    
    observeEvent(input$checkGroup, {
        leafletProxy("map", data = mydata_filtered()) %>%
            clearGroup ("checkGroup") %>%
            addMarkers(
                lng =  ~ longitude,
                lat = ~ latitude,
                group = "checkGroup",
                popup = ~ content
            )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

